# Best Approach to Get People to Put all Require Information in a single ticket?

Tags: communication, tasks, jira

At the agency I work at, I notice that to finish a task, I end up perusing several sources to get the assets I need. (The initial ticket in Jira, Gmail, Drive, etc)

I feel as though everything I need (or, if I'm delegating a task, everything the person who's assigned needs) should be at least linked in their work task.

How can I encourage people to put all required information directly in the initial ticket?

Comment: Unfortunately questions seeking opinions are off topic for this site and therefore your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Maybe you can reformulate your question to ask how to deal with such a circumstance. I can imagine others have this problem too.

Comment: Have a look on this page to avoid off-topic posts: http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your gut feeling is pointing you in the right direction, toward the practice of **full kitting** tasks before those tasks are initiated.

Essentially, full kitting means that all of the inputs requires to complete a task are collected into a set before that task is initiated. Inputs can include information (manuals, instructions, data), physical materials, tools that will be used to do the work, and the availability of needed resources and people. I'm having difficulty finding a quality, online reference to link to. Kitting is a concept used in both *Theory of Constraints* and *Lean* methodologies.

Some tools for kitting in software projects include:

1. Public source code repositories like GitHub or GitLab
2. Wikis for documentation
3. User stories with acceptance criteria
4. Wireframe user interface mockups
5. Links to deployed web services

All of the above can be associated with a Jira task as it moves through your team's workflow, either as an attachment or linked resource. This approach will likely work with other software too if your team chooses a different took than Jira. Some software, for example [Kanbanery](http://kanbanery.com), will allow a task to be marked as "ready to pull" meaning that all elements of the kit have been collected and the task is ready for a team member to begin working on it.

Comment: Awesome! Is there a link you can point me to with more info?

Comment: I will try to add better references soon. When I drafted the answer above I noticed that a lot of the "kitting" material appears to be elaborated in books and offline resources (most Theory of Constraints material is either in books or material owned by consultants). That's unfortunate. Hopefully I can find some public references.

Comment: I've been looking around for "full kitting" but I'm not finding anything. I would like to push this amongst the PM's here, but I need something a bit more solid ;)

Comment: @Martin, [Realization](http://www.realization.com/), a critical chain project management consulting company, is one place you can go for professional-grade assistance.

Comment: @Martin, here is an article on the basic concepts of [kitting](http://www.valuestreamguru.com/?p=161). As used in the article, "kitting" is a term from the manufacturing practice of "Kanban". It is reasonable to apply Kanban manufacturing concepts to Kanban software development workflows.

Comment: @Martin, it may be useful to consider the literal example of a Lego set as a kit. A Lego set includes everything needed to build a specific Lego structure: blocks, instructions, and sometimes tools or stickers. It is intuitive that it will take less time for a child to construct a Lego castle starting from a complete kit than it would take for a child to source all the parts, instructions, and tools individually.

Comment: @Martin, O'Reilly has a book due out this month that may offer additional guidance (I can't say for sure because the table of contents isn't yet available. [Real-World Kanban](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781680500776.do).

Comment: @Martin, the Theory of Constraints Industry Consortium has a [page of freely available materials](http://www.tocico.org/?page=toc_portal). One of the presentations, "Managing new product development projects...", begins to address kitting.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I'll check these all out and check back!

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree that it helps a lot, to bring all necessary information together. Nothing annoys more than going through some tree structure searching for an information several times a day.

What I learned is, that **using systems that provide URLs simplifies this issue a lot** (e.g. web links):

- URLs can be processed by a lot of tools
- The URL target application can be independent from the application the link is presented
- Opening the URL is a simple click

Most modern system engineering tools provide URLs / links to call specific information (Jira, Confluence Wiki, Doors, git, ...).

What ever tool you are using to provide task descriptions, it will be most likely able to deal with links (e.g. web browser MS Word).